# Is there a clean pattern for implementing an in-place grid editor with razor and EF?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, razor, webgrid

I'm looking to implement an in-place grid editor but the data schema doesn't fit into the expected view.
The model looks like two entities - one that contains the store location (first column) but the recurring data is date based across the rest of the columns. New data elements are created per day.
I'd like to be able to click on a cell, and automatically be placed into an edit mode so it looks like the spreadsheet example. I'm wondering if this can be done in a grid, or should I create a user control that loads by date with a repeater? Any help is appreciated! 
(I can't post an image so I'll do my best here!)

> (simulated spreadsheet!)

```
          Oct 1           Oct 2         Oct 3.....         
          Screws   Nuts   Screws  Nuts
Store1      35      35      22     25
 Shelf1     10      10       9      9
 Shelf2     16      16      11     11
 Shelf3      9       9      12     16
Store2
 Shelf1
 Shelf2
```

The new data rows are displayed as columns with new dates